# Error when trying to replace certain files when using a loop in ansible

Tags: linux, automation, scripting, ansible

We rolled out some files to users using Ansible, but now we want to replace those files with new ones, but only if those don't have certain info in.

The files:

test users file.txt

```
DATA=1000
OTHERDATA=SOMESTUFF
```

test2 users file.txt

```
DATA=1000000
```

So I want to keep test's file.txt, and replace test2's file.txt

This is my replace.yml file

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Find which users file.txt needs to be replaced
    shell: grep -Fx "DATA=1000" '/home/{{ item.name }}/file.txt'
    with_items:
      - name: test
      - name: test2
    register: find_output
    ignore_errors: True

  - debug:
      var: find_output

  - name: Replace file.txt for only users that need it
    copy:
      src: 'file_orig.txt'
      dest: '/home/{{ item.name }}/file.txt'
      owner: '{{ item.name }}'
      mode: 0644
    with_items: "{{ find_output.results }}"
    when:
      - find_output.rc == 1

  - debug:
      var: find_output
```

The first section finds the the files, but second section gives an error

```
     fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
        "msg": "The conditional check 'find_output.rc == 1' failed. The error was: error while 
evaluating conditional (find_output.rc == 1): 'list object' has no attribute 'rc'\n\nThe error appears 
to be in '/home/user/replace.yml': line 43, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the 
exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: test\n    ^ here\n"
    }
```

Here is the debug output

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "find_output": {
        "changed": true, 
        "failed": true, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "grep -Fx \"DATA=1000\" '/home/test/file.txt'", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.001330", 
                "end": "2019-11-24 00:19:27.046976", 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "grep -Fx \"DATA=1000\" '/home/test/file.txt'", 
                        "_uses_shell": true, 
                        "argv": null, 
                        "chdir": null, 
                        "creates": null, 
                        "executable": null, 
                        "removes": null, 
                        "stdin": null, 
                        "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                        "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                        "warn": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": {
                    "name": "test"
                }, 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2019-11-24 00:19:27.045646", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "DATA=1000", 
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "DATA=1000"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "grep -Fx \"DATA=1000\" '/home/test2/file.txt'", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.001332", 
                "end": "2019-11-24 00:19:27.118452", 
                "failed": true, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "grep -Fx \"DATA=1000\" '/home/test2/file.txt'", 
                        "_uses_shell": true, 
                        "argv": null, 
                        "chdir": null, 
                        "creates": null, 
                        "executable": null, 
                        "removes": null, 
                        "stdin": null, 
                        "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                        "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                        "warn": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": {
                    "name": "test2"
                }, 
                "msg": "non-zero return code", 
                "rc": 1, 
                "start": "2019-11-24 00:19:27.117120", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "", 
                "stdout_lines": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"'list object' has no attribute 'rc'"*

```
    find_output.rc == 1
```

A: The task below should do the job

```
      - name: Replace file.txt for only users that need it
        copy:
          src: 'file_orig.txt'
          dest: '/home/{{ item.item.name }}/file.txt'
          owner: '{{ item.item.name }}'
          mode: 0644
        loop: "{{ find_output.results }}"
        when: item.rc == 1
```

- *find_output.results* is a list
- The *loop* puts each item of the list into the variable *item*
- The variable *item* has attributes

```
    item.item.name
    item.rc
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the help, this solved my issue, I have now tested on my live test environment, and it worked as expected.